# Whats the meaning of odd beast?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I don't know what this type of words are called in Linguistics?  **I guess its a metaphor**. But I come across many types of these words when I read online articles. Now its the biggest challenge to me. Here is one of them. I will post many these words in future.

> Internet Explorer is an **odd beast**. Treated like an application, it’s also considered a Windows component. In fact, it’s such a component of Windows that you may be able to make the shortcuts and icons related to IE go away, but you can never really get rid of everything. Some components simply are parts of Windows.

Answer (score 2):

You ask an interesting question. Yes, it is a metaphor, since a web browser isn't literally a non-sentient animal. It's a common (well, common-ish) metaphor to compare unfamiliar things to wild animals—compare [this recent question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/54151/what-kind-of-an-animal-vs-what-kind-of-animal?s=1%7C0.3814) concerning comparing Java to an animal.

So the writer is simply saying that Internet Explorer is odd.

I look forward to your future posts. :)