# Zero articles after "of"?

Tags: articles, prepositional-phrases

I learned that I always have to use an article before a countable noun with some exceptions.

But I am not sure this is right time to omit the article

> The old model of traditional kiln
>
> A new paradigm of tourist attraction

The examples above are excerpted from professional articles and I just wonder they are typo or right usage of zero article.

Thank you!

Comment: In both of your examples, the noun represents the _entire class_ of the thing in question, almost as if it were a proper name. The same applies when we use a noun after _kind of_ and _type of_; we say _"A new kind of kiln"_ and _"A new type of attraction"_. This is a standard use of the zero article.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I read few articels about the article and generalization and it feels like I have to pluralize traditional kiln and tourist attraction.

Comment: Use zero article with plural countable nouns and with uncountable nouns to refer to a representative of the class of things (e.g. Mobile phones have revolutionised . . . ;Technology is revolutionising the way people communicate.)

Comment: or adding "the" can be an answer perhaps? 

[Use the definite article (the) to refer to an entire class of things (e.g. The mobile phone has revolutionised communications.)]

Comment: Related: [what kind of a person vs what kind of person](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/61408/48335)

Comment: Related:  [what kind of an animal vs. what kind of animal](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/54151/2127)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Although in general we precede a singular, uncountable noun with a *determiner* such as the indefinite article **a(n)** or the definite article **the**, there are many instances in which we use the zero article (which means no article at all) before such a noun.

We use the zero article when the noun expresses a reference to a general class of things. The most common examples of this usage are phrases which use the expressions *kind of*, *type of*, and *sort of*:

- I like that kind of pickle
- He plays a special type of guitar.
- What sort of car is it?

It is not only after *kind of*, *type of*, and *sort of* that the zero article is used. There are many times when we use a noun to represent a class of things:

- What brand of cracker do you like?
- Ford is my favorite make of automobile.
- Cherry is the best flavor of pie.

In your examples, the nouns *kiln* and *attraction* do not refer to specfic, individual things. Instead, they represent *kilns* and *attractions* in general:

- The old model of traditional kiln

*Kiln* here refers not to a specific individual kiln, but to all kilns of the traditonal type (or model.)

- A new paradigm of tourist attraction

*Attraction* here refers not to a specific individual attraction, but to attractions as a concept.

Comment: Would you please tell me what's the difference between an uncountable noun and a singular noun, both take singular verbs I guess. "The rice is on that part of the shelf" I think it's wrong to say **a** rice is ... . In other words, I think all the uncountable nouns are singular. Perhaps, I am neglecting something.

Comment: @Cardinal _Police_ is an example of a plural uncountable noun.

Comment: I see. I think my objection comes from the fact that I learned to judge nouns based on the type of verb they take. I must admit that I always considered police a noun as plural as "eggs".

Comment: @Cardinal _Police_, like _scissors_, takes a plural verb, and has no singular form. You can learn more by searching for the phrase _plurale tantum_.

Comment: "You can learn more by searching for the phrase _plurale tantum_" --between wind and water, товарищ!