# Curious use of the definite article with body parts in dictionary definitions

Tags: definite-article

I've come across the following definition of *plectrum* in the *Oxford Dictionary of English*, which can be found at https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/plectrum:

> A thin flat piece of plastic, tortoiseshell, or other slightly flexible material held by or worn on **the fingers** and used to pluck the strings of a musical instrument such as a guitar.

This isn't an isolated use of the definite article with parts of the human body in this context. Other examples include definitions of
[*shoe*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/shoe),

> A covering for **the foot**, typically made of leather, having a sturdy sole and not reaching above the ankle.

[*thimble*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/thimble), [*hat*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hat), and so on.

---

What's the reason behind the use of the definite article in *worn on **the fingers***, *covering for **the foot***, and so on?

From what I know, the definite article is used when the reader is expected to know and recognize its referent – but I don't know what or whose fingers the definition makes reference to; *the fingers* don't seem unique or well-known, and neither they nor their possessor (the person or very adroit animal) is mentioned or implied – something that would otherwise help infer their existence. The same goes for *the foot*, etc.

Body parts are an example of something usually [inalienable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inalienable_possession) (courtesy of [snailplane](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/230/)), the fact which might be of help when answering this question.

Comment: English for the most part doesn't distinguish alienable vs inalienable possession, so that point isn't really relevant.

Comment: @eques I know, but so far that's the only common denominator for these words, unless you count body parts as some special category.

Comment: but as you said there is no specified possessor (which isn't in any case the criteria for definite vs indefinite article use). Some article uses are more "customary"

Comment: @eques It's not a necessary criterion, but it can be a sufficient one.

Comment: +1.  This is an awesome question.  If I could, I would give a bonus for this question.

Comment: I think you may get a better response to this question on [English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com). Possibly related: [English syntax rules based on word choice](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/147686/english-syntax-rules-based-on-word-choice)

Answer (score 8):

As described **[here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/137742/37009)**, it is idiomatic to use the *zero article* in some possessive phrases which refer to a thing as representative of sub-class within a class:

- this type of guitar
- that make of car
- what sort of plectrum

It is also idiomatic to use the *definite article* with the singular or plural noun when that noun refers to a thing as representative of an entire class of things.<sup>†</sup>

Examples abound:

- **The capo d'astro** is affixed to **the neck** of **the guitar**.
- **The computer** has changed our world.
- **The Dodo** is an extinct pigeon-like bird.
- An example of the order *Rosales* is **the rose**.
- This pathogen infects **the rose tree** through the cut surface of the graft.

  1

  A shoe is a covering for **the foot**.

  **The unicorn** is a mythical beast.

  Multiple <s>plectra</s> plectrums are worn on **the fingers**.

  "**The rose** looks fair, but fairer we it deem..." <sup>‡</sup>

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Note that this is true of all nouns, not just those which refer to parts of the body.</sub>
<sup>‡</sup> <sub>William Shakespeare, Sonnet LIV</sub>
1<sub>[GEMES-ROSES - Disease and pest control](http://www.gemes-roses.com/en/disease_and_pest_control_en.php)</sub>

Comment: I can't find any other definitions that use the definite generic in that manner in that dictionary; it seems that such usage is confined to body parts (and maybe musical instruments, but they're a science for themselves and I won't go into that). Further, the [definite generic construction](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html) isn't commonly used with "normal" plural countable nouns (see Quirk et al. p.283: they list nationalities, groups of people (e.g., *the blind*), and "in scientific descriptions [...] like *the rodents* (referring to the whole order Rodentia)") .

Comment: @userr2684291 In _"The computer has changed our world"_, there is neither body part nor musical instrument, and surely The late, lamented  Great Auk fails to satisfy those criteria as well! This is a well-known and widely explained usage of the def. article, see e.g.. **[here](https://www.englishgrammar.org/definite-article/)**. I think Lawler will agree, if he happens to read this. He's around. As he says in that article: _"It's not that the articles the or a have special meaning"_.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is used constantly in those Attenborough BBC nature shows.

Comment: @Catija Yep, it's very common in discussion of species. (Someone is going to ask, soon, why "Baby" has the zero article in such things as: "Now, before pulling the diaper up, turn baby over..." I've yet to hear a plausible explanation for that one.)

Comment: I think that's regional. I'd say "turn *the* baby over". When they're saying "turn Baby over" I'm pretty sure they're using it as a name, not as a descriptor.

Comment: @Catija No, this is a _famous_ oddity. In baby instruction books of the recent past, "baby" was presented unaccompanied, and this is still common, e.g. see [this](http://www.healthguidance.org/entry/14336/1/How-to-Burp-a-Baby.html) and also comments [here](https://babiesfirstlactation.wordpress.com/2013/08/09/the-newborns-stomach/comment-page-1/) and [here](http://forums.llli.org/showthread.php?121923-Newborn-Not-Satisfied-After-Nursing) for things like "when baby burps".

Comment: The question is specifically about *dictionary definitions*, and the only examples you give that are in the form of definitions refer to body parts (or anthropomorphized parts of instruments). A quick glance at some similar definitions suggests that the OP might be on to something—e.g. Oxford Dictionaries' [**tablecloth** A cloth spread over ***a*** table](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tablecloth) and [**bedspread** A decorative cloth used to cover ***a*** bed when it is not in use.](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bedspread) Not *the* table or *the* bed.

Comment: @1006a The Great Auk could be thought of as a body part, I suppose, if we consider the entire bird a part of itself, but what are we to do with the rose?

Comment: The [great auk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_auk) is much more like a penguin than a pigeon! But, hey, this isn't [biology.se].SE. :-)

Comment: Some of this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63569/discussion-on-answer-by-p-e-dant-curious-use-of-the-definite-article-with-body).

Answer (score 7):

The definite article is sometimes used to indicate that the noun refers to a type rather than to a specific person or thing. For example:

> The beginning writer faces many frustrations.

Unless there is a character called "the beginning writer" in the context, this is a generalization about the problems people who decide to become writers face. It does not refer to any specific person.

In contrast "A beginning writer faces many frustrations." is probably about a specific writer. We might find this phrase in the summary of the plot of a film.

Sentences such as this will sound odd to the English speaker:

> Electric lights, telegraphs, and phonographs are great 19th century inventions.

The electric light in my garage is not an invention. The electric light (the technology) is. Instead we would say:

> The electric light, the telegraph, and the phonograph are great 19th century inventions.

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary is combining two definitions into one:

... held by or worn on the fingers

When a single plectrum is used, it is normally held not worn. When multiple plectrums are used, they are "worn on the fingers".

A single plectrum can be worn on **a finger**.

Several can be worn on **the fingers**.

Which fingers?

Why, the ones not on the foot but on the hand.

Which hand?  The hand that members of the species homo sapiens tend to have two of.

Comment: Which members? The members who...

Comment: Which members? *All* members.  (no article)

Comment: hrm. I have no problem with _"Which members? Why, all **the** members."_

Comment: You can say "all the members" if you wish, but I'd say "all members".