# Why did they use the definite article in "the basketball court"?

Tags: articles, definite-article

I was reading [an article](http://www.cnn.com/2017/08/04/sport/usain-bolt-in-numbers-2017-iaaf-world-athletics-championships/index.html) about Usain Bolt on CNN's website and there is this sentence.

> With his height and weight, the world record holder would not look out of place on the basketball court.

Why is the definite article used in "the basketball court"? It could be any court and also the court was not mentioned before in the text.

Comment: The definite article is often used when the noun represents the entire class to which it belongs. See **[this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/138464/37009)**.

Comment: Looks like DAMS has struck again (see [**this answer**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/22647/uses-of-the-definite-article-the-in-generic-noun-phrases/22650#22650) as well).

Comment: @P.E.Dant  So, the court represents the entire class?

Comment: @J.R. I still prefer the non-Bowdlerized _Definite Article Meaning Nonstability Incomprehension Trauma_.

Comment: Yes, "the basketball court" refers to basketball courts in general, or as it might also be expressed, to "basketball courts" as an environment.